# Custom Delphi Colours

Tags: delphi, colors, delphi-7

If i want to set a colour property to something thats non-standard (i.e. not something like clBlack or clRed) how can i do this? Can i set something like hexadecimal colours?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

RGB in Windows.pas

```
function RGB(r, g, b: Byte): COLORREF;
```

you can cast the result to be a TColor.

e.g

```
MyColour := TColor(RGB(Red,Green,Blue));
```

Comment: Normally, casting is done implicitly. A COLORREF and a `TColor` both are 32-bit integers. Hence, `MyColour := RGB(Red,Green,Blue);` will work just fine.

Answer (score 12):

you can use $00BBGGRR

BB = Blue
GG = Green
RR = Red

All these values can be between 0 and 255 ($00 and $FF)

Comment: I tried this, but it worked for me only if I used $FF on the beginning - so $FFBBGGRR

Comment: @Asped: No, the highest byte in the DWORD should be 0 for a normal colour. But maybe you are using colours with an alpha channel? If so, $FF is probably full opacity. But alpha isn't normally used in Win32 GDI.

Answer (score 3):

I always used RGB macro: http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/RGB

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check [Colors in Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Colors_in_VCL) help page. If might be useful for Delphi developers who do web programming because `Vcl.Graphics` unit defines `TColor` values as `clWeb____` web-friendly constants.

Many constants are already predefined and before you use them you can visually see how the colors look like. So there is no need to do RBG "mixes".